# Electric field along the axis of a rod

Tags: electrostatics, integration

I'm having difficulties with a specific Electrostatics problem.

I'm given an isolated rod of length $L$ with its endpoints at $x=0$ and $x=L$. Also, the rod has a linear charge density of $\lambda =q\sqrt{x}$. I'm asked to calculate the electric field for $x>L$ ($y=0$, $z=0)$.

I've tried to calculate the contribution from a small segment $dx'$ of the rod to the electric field and then integrate this from $0$ to $L$.

Doing this, I arrived at the following integral:
$$\vec{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{0}^{L}\frac{\sqrt{x'}}{(L+x-x')^2}dx'$$

I've tried to solve this integral for quite some time now (also tried my luck with Wolfram Alpha) but it doesn't seem to work out. I think I'm overlooking some aspect of the problem but I can't quite see it.

It would be awesome if anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong could give me a small hint on this one. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, your definition of $x$ is inconsistent. If you'd like to find the electric field at $x > L$ while the rod is located in $ 0 \leq x' \leq L$, your integral should be $\int_{0}^{L} \frac{\alpha \sqrt{x'}}{(x-x')^{2}} dx'$.

Comment: Expand the denominator in terms of $\left(\frac{x'}{x}\right)^n$.

Comment: To elaborate on Tom Ariel, ( x - x') is the distance between the field point and the charge element. That square root still makes for a difficult integral.